How do you say "Remember to breathe, be here, and be now." in Latin
I'm looking for the Latin translation of "Remember to breathe, be here, and be now," which is my mantra for helping with anxiety and obtrusive thoughts. Take a deep breath, calm down, and center yourself or achieve mindfulness (for context). Thanks.

I'll bet there's a nice idiomatic Latin way to say this, that is a long way from a literal translation. My Latin isn't good enough to think of it, but give it time and one of our experts here might.

My attempt would be: "Memento ut spires, ut hic sis, et ut nunc sis."
Memento - Imperative of "memini" meaning "to remember".
ut - a conjunction meaning "so that"
spires - 2nd person present subjunctive of "spiro" meaning "to breathe"
hic - an adverb meaning "here"
sis - 2nd person present subjunctive of "sum" meaning "to be"
et - conjunction meaning "and"
nunc - an adverb meaning "now"

Are there examples in classical literature of that imperative used with an ut clause like you do here? It doesn't sound familiar to me, but it could well be just my forgetfulness.

@JoonasIlmavirta Allen & Greenough §449c suggests cūrā ut and fac ut as periphrastic imperatives, but I don't think that applies here. But §563 says that many verbs denoting an action directed toward the future, such as resolving to do something, take an ut clause as their object (including imperative cūrā). No memention of mementō, though.

@BenKovitz Cura/fac/vide + ut were also what I thought of. I think those ut-clauses are technically result clauses. So, cura ut ualeas = "take care [ut=with the result that (in the future)] you be well." Lewis and Short do have a few examples of memento + ut, though it's not typical.
